# Configure remote Python interpreter in PyCharm: Error file pycharm_helpers_5

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to add a new SSH interpreter to my project. I followed these steps:
Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> Cog icon -> Add.. -> SSH Interpreter
I enter the host and username and password and click next. 
I can see 'Connected to username@host:22' and I choose the sync folders on my local machine and on remote and I get the error in the screenshot after clicking on finish

[PyCharm Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNwPv.png)

I noticed that the path in the error does not correspond to my home directory on the remote server. Also, there's no .pycharm_helpers_5 or anything related to PyCharm in this path. I don't have sudo rights on the server and to my understanding, PyCharm is trying to upload the helpers to that location but is being denied access.

How can I change this path to /home/username where I have write permission?

Comment: There should be an auto detect feature there. It's generally beside where you specify the path. Check within deployment settings.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's the same path in the screenshot, but I don't have write permission there..

Comment: Also I tried to change it to my home directory but I still get the same error with the same path...so I don't think this the way to change it

Comment: Did you configure the mappings?

Comment: AFAIK, the folder sync is handled by the deployment settings. So, your SSH interpreter has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yeah I did, yeah I tried to change the path in the deployment settings..